# How to use Python super() when returning values and keeping track of internal state?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, super

I am attempting to construct a toy example of class inheritance calling `super()` in Python (3.7.6). I'd like to keep track of the state of the middle class in the chain, and I would like to have the class method that is delegated return a value. I thought this should be straightforward, but I am getting a strange result.

(I am basing the minimal example on [this tutorial](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).)

I can set up an example where the middle class keeps track of state, no problem:

```
In [1]: class Root:
   ...:     def draw(self):
   ...:         # the delegation chain stops here
   ...:         assert not hasattr(super(), 'draw')
   ...: 
   ...: class Shape(Root):
   ...:     def __init__(self, shapename, **kwds):
   ...:         self.shapename = shapename
   ...:         self.has_run = False
   ...:         super().__init__(**kwds)
   ...:     def draw(self):
   ...:         if not self.has_run:
   ...:             print('Drawing for the first time.  Setting shape to:', self.shapename)
   ...:             self.has_run = True
   ...:         else:
   ...:             print('Drawing again.  Setting shape to:', self.shapename)
   ...: 
   ...:         super().draw()
   ...: 
   ...: class ColoredShape(Shape):
   ...:     def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
   ...:         self.color = color
   ...:         super().__init__(**kwds)
   ...:     def draw(self):
   ...:         print('Drawing.  Setting color to:', self.color)
   ...:         super().draw()
   ...: 
   ...: cs = ColoredShape(color='blue', shapename='square')
   ...: print('*** first pass')
   ...: cs.draw()
   ...: print('*** second pass')
   ...: cs.draw()
*** first pass
Drawing.  Setting color to: blue
Drawing for the first time.  Setting shape to: square
*** second pass
Drawing.  Setting color to: blue
Drawing again.  Setting shape to: square
```

However, as soon as I modify the methods to return a value, I lose the ability to keep track of state:

```
In [2]: class Root:
   ...:     def draw(self):
   ...:         # the delegation chain stops here
   ...:         assert not hasattr(super(), 'draw')
   ...: 
   ...: class Shape(Root):
   ...:     def __init__(self, shapename, **kwds):
   ...:         self.shapename = shapename
   ...:         self.has_run = False
   ...:         super().__init__(**kwds)
   ...:     def draw(self):
   ...:         if not self.has_run:
   ...:             print('Drawing for the first time.  Setting shape to:', self.shapename)
   ...:             return 'a'
   ...:             self.has_run = True
   ...:         else:
   ...:             print('Drawing again.  Setting shape to:', self.shapename)
   ...:             return 'b'
   ...:         super().draw()
   ...: 
   ...: class ColoredShape(Shape):
   ...:     def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
   ...:         self.color = color
   ...:         super().__init__(**kwds)
   ...:     def draw(self):
   ...:         print('Drawing.  Setting color to:', self.color)
   ...:         foo = super().draw()
   ...:         return [foo] * 3
   ...: 
   ...: cs = ColoredShape(color='blue', shapename='square')
   ...: print('*** first pass')
   ...: out = cs.draw()
   ...: print(out)
   ...: print('*** second pass')
   ...: out = cs.draw()
   ...: print(out)
*** first pass
Drawing.  Setting color to: blue
Drawing for the first time.  Setting shape to: square
['a', 'a', 'a']
*** second pass
Drawing.  Setting color to: blue
Drawing for the first time.  Setting shape to: square
['a', 'a', 'a']
```

I feel like I am missing something fundamental about the functionality of `super()`, and I would appreciate any help people could give!

Answer (score 0):

This was a very silly mistake. In the middle class in the chain, I was returning before setting the internal state variable. This is corrected by updating the state variable before any return statements.

Corrected code below:

```
class Root:
    def draw(self):
        # the delegation chain stops here
        assert not hasattr(super(), 'draw')

class Shape(Root):
    def __init__(self, shapename, **kwds):
        self.shapename = shapename
        self.has_run = False
        super().__init__(**kwds)
    def draw(self):
        if not self.has_run:
            print('Drawing for the first time.  Setting shape to:', self.shapename)
            out = 'a'
            self.has_run = True
        else:
            print('Drawing again.  Setting shape to:', self.shapename)
            out = 'b'
        super().draw()
        return out

class ColoredShape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(**kwds)
    def draw(self):
        print('Drawing.  Setting color to:', self.color)
        foo = super().draw()
        return [foo] * 3

cs = ColoredShape(color='blue', shapename='square')
print('*** first pass')
out = cs.draw()
print(out)
print('*** second pass')
out = cs.draw()
print(out)
```

Comment: Explain the mistake and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, just edited